# "Unbound module Pervasives" error when using OCaml build system in Sublime Text 3

Tags: ocaml, sublimetext3

I'm trying to create a build system for OCaml in sublime text 3 on Windows 8.1. I installed `OCaml` via `opam` in Cygwin and typed the following into the `OCaml.sublime-build` file:

```
{
"cmd": ["C:/OCaml64/home/LENOVO/.opam/4.05.0+mingw64c/bin/ocaml.exe", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.ml"
}
```

I'm trying the build system out with a `test.ml` that contains `print_endline "hello world";;`. I can run the command directly from the terminal with the `ocaml` interactive command line or using `ocaml test.ml`. But when I open the file in Sublime Text 3 and run `Ctrl-B`, I get the following error:

```
File "command line", line 1:
Error: Unbound module Pervasives
```

I searched for this error online but could not find much that applies to my situation. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: As a complete shot in the dark, are you sure you saved your `ml` file before you ran the build? I'm not familiar with that language, but the way it's saying "command line" as the input file sort of sounds like perhaps it's thinking you're entering text on the fly and not from a file, which would be the case if the file you're trying to build doesn't exist on disk yet.

Comment: @OdatNurd Yes I did save the file; thanks for the reminder though!

Comment: Worth a shot. :)

Comment: For me it looks like the OCaml compiler you are calling cannot find its libraries. Which environment does Sublime Text provide for the called processes? I.e. is `CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or similar defined in this environment?

Comment: Hi @mschmidt ! I typed `$ printenv CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in a Cygwin terminal and got `C:/OCaml64/home/LENOVO/.opam/4.05.0+mingw64c/lib/stublibs`.

Comment: And I have added the above to my `Main.sublime-menu---OCaml`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem with OcaIDE under Eclipse, if you installed Ocaml following [this tutorial](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/)
then this solution should work for you too, simply from Cygwin terminal type: 
`ocaml-env-win -- "<insert the path to sublime text>"`.


This should launch Sublime Text with the proper environment settings.

Source : https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/ocaml-env/#program-startup.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

This error means, that the compiler cannot find the interface file (the `pervasives.cmi` file) for the `Pervasives` module. By default, the compiler searches in the current folder first, then in the standard library directory. You can add more directories using the `-I` option, however in your case, `Pervasives` should be in the standard library.

The path to the standard library is compiled in the compiler and is specified during the configuration of the compiler, use `ocamlc -where` to print the path.

In your case, this path either doesn't exist (e.g., you removed it, assuming that it is a non-necessary build artifact, or just moved in a different place), not accessible (some permission problems), or doesn't contain the library code (i.e., cmi, cmo, cmx, and other files). In any case, it is a problem with your installation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! It seems that the path exists as I got `C:/OCaml64/home/LENOVO/.opam/4.05.0+mingw64c/lib/ocaml` by typing `ocamlc -where`, and I found the `pervasives.cmi` file in the folder. I followed https://github.com/protz/ocaml-installer/wiki to install OCaml (I actually uninstalled and re-installed it after first encountering the problem, but nothing changed); everything works fine from the command line, but I just couldn't set things up in Sublime Text 3. Would you happen to have suggestions as to whether this is a known problem on Windows platform?